# not selector with placeholder

Tags: css, selector, placeholder

I have input type whom I am differentiating with data attributes:

I want all data-type to hide placeholder except for date field

I am not able to use :not selector. Answer with **input[type="text"]** will not be accepted as there may be n number of data-types apart from text and date.

```css
    :not(input[data-type="date"])::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
        color: transparent !important;
    }
     :not(input[data-type="date"]):-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
       color: transparent !important;
    }
    :not(input[data-type="date"])::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
       color: transparent !important;
    }
     :not(input[data-type="date"]):-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
       color: transparent !important;
    }
```

```html
<input data-type="text" placeholder="Enter date">
<input data-type="date" placeholder="Enter text">
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are. Nice solution btw referring to `transparent`.

```css
input:not([data-type="date"])::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
  color: transparent !important;
}
input:not([data-type="date"]):-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: transparent !important;
}
input:not([data-type="date"])::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: transparent !important;
}
input:not([data-type="date"]):-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<input data-type="text" placeholder="Enter date">
<input data-type="date" placeholder="Enter text">
```

Comment: Hell, i tried this solution but I guess in wrong way which made me to post the question. Your solution works fine. Thank you.

Comment: NiZa is correct @ShoaibChikate. [`:not` selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#negation) takes only simple selector as argument and as per spec - *A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.*. This means `input[data-type="date"]` is not a simple selector.

Comment: @Harry: Thank you for explaination